# How to push a view controller as a full screen from the view controller presented as a half-modal

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I am trying to push a view controller from a view controller which is presented as a bottom-half Modal. When I try to push the view controller, it showed up within the bounds of the presented bottom-half view.

How can I push a new view controller as a full screen view on to the navigation stack from a view controller which is presented as a bottom-half modal?

Comment: Use delegate / protocol pattern... bottom-half view controller defines a protocol; "main view controller" conforms to that protocol and sets itself as the delegate for presented bottom-half view; button tap (or whatever action) in bottom-half tells its delegate to execute the protocol function.

Comment: DonMag, here the problem is with height of the pushed view controller, since presented modal view controller pushes a new view controller, it is showing within the bounds of the presented bottom-half view.

Comment: You have a Navigation Controller, yes? And from the current VC in the NavVC, you present a modal VC that shows on the bottom-half of the screen, yes? And you want a button tap in that modal VC to push a new VC onto the NavVC, yes? And you want the modal VC to be dismissed at the same time?

Comment: Yes, I have a navigation controller, and presented a modal VC which shows as a bottom-half of the screen. Yes, when I tap in that bottom-half would like to push to a new VC onto the NavVC. No I don't want modal VC to be dismissed, this what ever new VC should be pushed from this presented modal VC.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this issue.

Have a Master Vie wController with full screen and clear colour and add a child view controller (which is basically a bottom-half view or content view) to it, and then present master view controller. Since master view controller is having full screen when you push a new view controller it shows in full screen. Content view is always bottom-half and we don't have to dismiss modal view controller.